# Need help for understanding SavedInstanceState in Activity

Tags: java, android, android-savedstate

I am having a problem where once you re open the application or the saved data on the viewpager disappear and only one view pager is visible. I have been wondering how can I handle this type of data loss with savedInstanceState:

So: I have this items:

```
@BindView(R.id.backToBudgetList)
ImageButton backButton;
@BindView(R.id.budgetTitle)
TextView tvBudgetTitle;
@BindView(R.id.budgetPeriod)
TextView tvBudgetPeriod;
@BindView(R.id.listBudgetTransactions)
ImageButton transListIB;
@BindView(R.id.line1)
TextView line1TV;
```

How can I write a good savedInstanceState for each entry Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Those views are in each view pager?

Comment: can you add your entire class code to check, since all methods are  not called when we re-started an already started activity.

Comment: @Daniel Yes they all are.

Comment: Is there a way to use one line of code to save it? like a boolean onRestore(true); @Daniel Kaveri